# How to compile curl with latest openssl (1.0.2) Debian

Tags: curl, openssl, debian

I am trying to compile curl with openssl 1.0.2 on a debian jessie machine.

```
$ which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
$ openssl version -d
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
```

I tried configuring curl in many different ways, for example

```
$ ./configure --with-ssl=/usr/lib/ssl
$ ./configure --with-ssl=/usr/bin/openssl // Makes no sense anyways
```

Now still, whatever I do, it does not compile with the right openssl version:

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.49.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.49.1 OpenSSL/1.0.1t [...]
```

How do I find out, which path to set?
Could it be, that I have to compile OpenSSL with the option "shared"? I installed openssl via apt-get.

**UPDATE**

So what I eventually did was, to add Debian Stretch Packages to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and installed OpenSSL 1.0.2, then libssl1.0.2 and finally libcurl4-openssl-dev.

After doing so, `curl -V` is not indicating any OpenSSL, but it works fine even with ALPN support, why I originally did all of this.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: ***"... with openssl 1.0.2 on a debian jessie machine...."*** - how did you configure OpenSSL? What did you use for `--openssldir`? And did the options include `shared`? Also see [Compilation and Installation](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: I installed OpenSSL 1.0.2 using `apt-get install openssl=1.0.2h-1`. To do so, you need to add the Debian Stretch Packackes to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`: I used the following:
`deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main` and 
`deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main`
Be careful, this is at your own risk! But it worked just fine for me.
I left the OpenSSL configuration default.

Answer (score 1):

curl's configure option `--with-ssl` needs the prefix to the install path you installed your OpenSSL in.

If you indeed installed your OpenSSL 1.0.2 in /usr/lib/ssl then `./configure --with-ssl=/usr/lib/ssl` is the correct line.

## Custom curl with custom OpenSSL

If you build openssl from source, you could for example do:

```
./config --prefix=/home/user/build-openssl
make
make install
```

and then build curl to use this custom OpenSSL build:

```
./configure --with-ssl=/home/user/build-openssl
```

## If configure fails

After configure has completed, you can load the `config.log` with your favorite editor and check for the OpenSSL checks and see what exactly that failed when it tried to find it.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer my question as I already have Openssl 1.0.2 on my machine. But I tried it anyway and it didn't work. Error in config.log: `/usr/bin/ld: /home/admin/build-openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'`

Comment: Your question doesn't give enough detail about your existing 1.0.2 install though as your curl invoke clearly shows it uses 1.0.1.

Comment: Yes, I agree! But I don't know how to find out more. Files are spread, /usr/bin, /usr/lib/ssl, ... And why does curl choose another OpenSSL version instead of failing? It's been 2 days of research, I am close to giving up.

Comment: well, how did you install the 1.0.2 version and where?

Comment: It didn't get much less confusing now. curl on debian uses gnutls by default afaik and that supports ALPN...

Comment: Can't say anything to that, only that openssl does not support ALPN in versions prior to 1.0.2. See the release notes here: https://www.openssl.org/news/openssl-1.0.2-notes.html

Comment: sure, that's old news, but you said your curl "is not indicating any OpenSSL" which then I guessed could imply it uses gnutls?